# Playing MP3 in Java Application

Tags: java, mp3

I want to play a MP3 file in my Java Application.
Because JavaLayer does not support pausing the music and JavaFX MediaPlayer is not nice to use due to Runtime distribution, I'm searching a library supporting playing, pausing and stopping MP3 files and if possible other formats, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JLayer does support pausing the music...

http://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/pausing-an-mp3-file-using-jlayer/

(Like the author says: the code is not quite beautiful or efficient - but it gets the job done. For alternatives and modified versions, scroll down to the comment section. The author also refers to another [solution](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1273085?tstart=255), but states that the "pausing" is delayed by 1 second.)